# Why is my program not recognizing the Checkerboard?

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I am running a Camera Calibration program from Python using openCV. I am using my computer camera from an XPS 15 9575 in order to capture different frames of a classic black and white checkerboard that I printed. For some reason, it never registers in the program that there is a checkerboard.

I've run this program by itself and with already produced images and it works. It only doesn't work as I try to capture new ones and process them instantly.

This is the beginning of the code. It runs to check to see if it finds the corners and then moves onto the next step. When running, it never makes it past this.

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cv2.namedWindow("test")

img_counter = 0
imgNames = []
size = (5,5)
while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    gray =  cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow("test", gray)
    if not ret:
        break
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k%256 == 27:
        break
    elif k%256 == 32:
        img_name = "{}.png".format(img_counter)
        imgtemp = cv2.imread(img_name)
        graytemp = cv2.cvtColor(imgtemp,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(graytemp, size,None)
        print (ret)
        if ret == True:
            print ("good!")
            imgNames.append(img_name)
            cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
            img_counter += 1
        else:
            print ("again")
```

Comment: For some reason, my previous explanations didn't go through so I just added it. Sorry!

Comment: Please add more detail as to where exactly the code fails. Do you see the "good!" or "again" printed to the console? 

It also looks like you have two separate frames here. You are still reading from your VideoCapture but also opening a new imgtemp from file? You are not actually calling any functions on the frame variable itself which is the image captured by the camera.

Comment: Ah sorry. So its captures an image an processes it. The "ret" value always returns false and prints "again." What the code is doing is processing the image and then saving it once it determines that it detects a checkerboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code above, you are trying to read an image which actually doesn't exist. See these lines:

```
img_name = "{}.png".format(img_counter)
imgtemp = cv2.imread(img_name)
```

Here, `img_name` is just a string, which doesn't point to an image file yet. You can do one thing, capture a frame and save it here and give it a name `img_name` and then try to read it via `cv2.imread` function, like below:

```
img_name = "{}.png".format(img_counter)
cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)       
imgtemp = cv2.imread(img_name)
```

Alternatively, you can replace `imgtemp = cv2.imread(img_name)` with `imgtemp = frame`. In this case, you don't have to save and then process a frame. Here, once a `spacebar` is pressed, processing is done on the current captured video frame without saving it.

And don't forget to add below lines at the end of your code:

```
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Ah thanks! And yup I have that I just didn't include it :)